# Semi-strict "and then" in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, operator-keyword

My problem is the following: First, I want to check whether a certain object exists, then I want to call a function on it. Example:

`if(obj_exists(my_object) && my_object.is_green()){...`

The second call obviously crashes the program if my_object isn't defined.
Question: Does "&&" guarantee execution in the order specified in the code? Does "&&" guarantee to stop if the first clause is false already? On all browsers/machines? Does this also apply to || (stops execution if the first clause is true already)?

Is it advisable to use:

`if(obj_exists(my_object) ? my_object.is_green() : false){...`

Because this would specify the order unambiguously. Is this version slower than the upper code sample?

Eiffel, the programming language, has an "and then" operator that solves this problem elegantly. I don't expect elegance from Javascript, just a viable solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Does "&&" guarantee to stop if the first clause is false already?"

Yes. The short circuit operators `&&` and `||` will only evaluate the operands until the result is known, contrary to their `&` and `|` counterparts.

Some languages have an `and then` or `AndAlso` operator. That corresponds to the `&&` operator in Javascript, as the `and` operator corresponds to the `&` operator.

Comment: There's another fundamental difference between && and &... The & is bitwise but && is not, it's simply a bool operator. I think you can't compare those operators like that. Is that right?

Comment: @Kenji: Good point. When used with boolean operands it doesn't matter that the `&` and `|` operators are bitwise, they work as logical operators. You are right that there are others uses for those operators, but I only meant to use their aspect as logical operators in the comparison.